# Python: Automatically Raise a Custom Exception Without Using The Command raise CustomException("Something Happened")

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I've been looking and couldn't find an answer. Basically, Is there a way to automatically raise a custom exception without using the command `raise CustomException("Something Happened")`? For Example: program calls 'FaultyFunction()' which then
causes a custom exception to occur without having a `raise CustomException("Something Bad Happened")` inside of the 'FaultyFunction()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a decorator that checks for faulty result and then raise an exception for you.

For example

```py
class CustomException(Exception):
    pass

def raise_custom_exception(on_returning=None, on_not_returning=None, message="Something happened"):
    def wrapper(fn):
        def wrapper2(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                returned = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as exc:
                raise CustomException(message + f", caused by: {exc}")
            if on_returning is not None:
                if returned == on_returning or \
                        isinstance(on_returning, tuple) and returned in on_returning:
                    raise CustomException(message)
            if on_not_returning is not None:
                if isinstance(on_not_returning, tuple) and returned not in on_not_returning \
                        or not isinstance(on_not_returning, tuple) and returned != on_not_returning:
                    raise CustomException(message)
            return returned
        return wrapper2
    return wrapper

# Usage

@raise_custom_exception(on_returning=42, message="Something is wrong")
def my_faulty_function(x):
    return x


@raise_custom_exception(on_not_returning=(200, 201), message="Server replied not okay")
def my_faulty_api_call(url):
    import requests
    print(f'calling ... {url}')
    return requests.get(url).status_code

# Use my_faulty_function and my_faulty_api_call
print(my_faulty_function(41))
try:
    my_faulty_function(42)
except Exception:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()

print(my_faulty_api_call("http://google.com"))
print(my_faulty_api_call("http://goooooooogle.com.does.not.exist"))
```

The output of this program is

```
41
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "faulty-raise.py", line 39, in <module>
    my_faulty_function(42)
  File "faulty-raise.py", line 14, in wrapper2
    raise CustomException(message)
CustomException: Something is wrong
calling ... http://google.com
200
calling ... http://goooooooogle.com.does.not.exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
...
```

As you can see, you can really craft the way how you would want this decorator to check for fault and raise the CustomException for you.

If you don't even want to decorate the function or the function is in some library you can just monkey patch it like this and use it.

```py
# In file some_faulty_library.py
def some_faulty_function_which_i_dont_even_want_to_decorate(*args, **kwargs):
    return None
# In file my_file_which_uses_faulty_library.py
import some_faulty_library
some_faulty_function_which_i_dont_even_want_to_decorate = raise_custom_exception(
    on_returning=(None,), message="This function always returns None. Stop using it.")(
    some_faulty_library.some_faulty_function_which_i_dont_even_want_to_decorate)

some_faulty_function_which_i_dont_even_want_to_decorate()
```