# How to raise exception for the entire project?

Tags: python, exception, decorator, fastapi

I know that if I want to raise an Exception I could use `raise CustomException()`

And to raise Exceptions automatically I could use a Decorator for my Function:
[Stack Overflow - Python: Automatically Raise a Custom Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481748/17905286)

But what if I want to do it on the whole project and not on single function?

For Example:
I have a FastApi Project and every time I am not authorized, I want to throw an Exception: NOT_AUTHORIZED(). Or if the user sends invalid SQL as a parameter, then I want to raise INVALID_SQL(). (**This should work without a Decorator on every function.**)

How do I raise this exception across the entire project?

Comment: You wrap those sections of code in `try`/`except` blocks. You should have a function or method where you check for authorization, so put one there. Same for where you parse/submit your SQL.

Comment: For FastAPI you usually add a dependency that retrieves the current user. This dependency then raises a custom `NotAuthorizedException` (or `HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='Not authorized')` if you want to use the built-in exception handling). "Having it raised on an entire project" doesn't make sense in itself, exceptions signal that a specific, unresolvable condition has occured and should be handled specifically for each case. Your database library probably raises an exception for invalid SQL already, so you can catch that in the FastAPI layer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your routes separated, that is to have routes that have SQL inputs in a router and the rest in the other routers, you can add a dependency for user authentication at app level, and SQL query check on router level.